# Initialise variable based on request path without using multiple if conditions?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to initialise a variable based on the request path, for e.g

```
let s;
if (req.path == "/a") {
    s = req.get.something1 + req.get.something2;
} else if (req.path == "/b") {
    s = req.get.something1 + req.get.something3;
} else if (req.path == "/c") {
    s = req.get.something4 + req.get.something2;
} else if (req.path == "/d") {
    s = req.get.something6 + req.get.something1;
} else if (req.path == "/e") {
    s = req.get.something2;
} else if (req.path == "/f") {
    s = req.get.something1;
} else if (req.path == "/g") {
    s = req.get.something4 + req.get.something6;
} else if (req.path == "/h") {
    s = req.get.something7 + req.get.something;
}....
```

I was thinking about initialising a map and then without using multiple ifs I can get the values, but the thing is as the value is dynamic based on the request so that approach will not work, I would have to write the if condition multiple times.

Is there any approach which would work without checking multiple ifs again and again and will be fast.

Comment: A map is the correct idea. Make it a map of functions if you need to run the code dynamically.

Comment: You could try [switch...case](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch) too, i think is better than multiple `else...if`.

Comment: @D.Smania Yes but that will take time for every request to first go into switch case and then do the initialisation.

Answer (score 1):

You might do map like this:

```js
const s_map = ({path, get}) => (
  {
    '/a': (get) => get.something1 + get.something2,
    '/b': (get) => get.something1 + get.something3,
    '/c': (get) => get.something2 + get.something3,
  }[path] || (() => undefined)
)(get)

let req = {
  path: '/a',
  get: {something1: 1, something2: 2, something3: 3}
}

let s = s_map(req)

console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch, it is nicer on the eyes

```
function valueOfPath (req) {

    switch (req.path) {
        case '/a':
            return (req.get.something1 + req.get.something2);
        case '/b':
            return (req.get.something1 + req.get.something3);
        case '/c':
            return (req.get.something4 + req.get.something2);
        case '/d':
            return (req.get.something6 + req.get.something1);
        case '/e':
            return (req.get.something2);
        case '/f':
            return (req.get.something1);
        case '/g':
            return (req.get.something4 + req.get.something6);
        case '/h':
            return (req.get.something7 + req.get.something);
        default:
            return (null);

    }
}
```

¯\_(ツ)_/¯